# Need assistance with PATH variables

Tags: c++, eclipse, variables, path

I am compiling C++ programs in Notepad++ and using command prompt to execute and run the programs. Initially I had this problem where the cmd said

> "g++" was not a recognized command.

I changed path variable and it was fine. But later when I was started Eclipse, it would not start. I had to change `PATH` variable again.

So my question is do I have to change the `PATH` variable every time I switch to running c++ and Eclipse or is there an alternative?

Comment: you can *add* paths to path.

Comment: I did. And is working:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tutorial if you're on windows 7 :

http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Once you set PATH variables, make sure to restart your computer. I've been in a similar situation and it was me just getting ahead of myself.